# Change layout in Lightspeed Webstore

Tags: php, yii, e-commerce

I've got a custom controller in my Lightspeed Webstore (an ecommerce framework built on Yii 1.1)

By default column2 is always the selected layout for pages, and I'm unable to change this.

Here's my example controller:

```
<?php

class ExampleController extends Controller {

    public $layout = "column2";

    public function actionIndex() {
        $this->layout = "column1";
        $this->render('index');
    }
```

The controller is located in controllers/ExampleController.php - and the index file is located in themes/brooklyn2014copy/example/index.php

This correctly renders the index page (i.e. domain.dev/example), but loads the wrong layout file. What do I need to do to change the layout file?

Comment: go to your Components/controller.php  there will be defined the default layoput settings... you can change there....!!!

Comment: The subdirectory there exists but it's empty...

Comment: Have you setup your config/main.php correctly to point to your brooklyn2014copy theme?

Comment: Well it's finding the right location of the view inside the theme ... that would imply that is setup correctly yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

normally `column2` file lies under the `layouts` folder. I assume you are working in a module. So you can override the attribute as

```
public $layout='/layouts/column2';
```

if you want to use column1 then

```
public $layout='/layouts/column1';
```

If you use above line then the layout will remains same throughout the controller. If you want to apply custom layout to each action you can use

```
public function actionYourAction()
{
$this->layout='/layouts/column2';
$this->render('your view');
}
```

Also you can do it in the specified view in which you want custom layout. You can mention it on the top of the page.Same code will work in the views.

Comment: Pretty close - in the view file at the top of the file this worked: $this->layout = "/layouts/column1"; If you edit your answer to mention the view / minor formatting difference I'll accept your answer too (I've given the bounty already).